# Why can't I call methods of instance variables in a class block?

Tags: java, oop

consider the below class

```
public class Player {

private int id;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Assume there is another class in the same package

```
public class Sample {
    Player p1 = new Player();
    Player p2 = new Player();
    Player p3 = new Player();
    Player p4 = new Player();
    //p1.
}
```

In this Class accessing the methods p1.setId(int) is not possible unless it is called in side another method

```
public class Sample {
    Player p1 = new Player();
    Player p2 = new Player();
    Player p3 = new Player();
    Player p4 = new Player();

    void example () {
        int x;
        p1.setId(x);                
    }
}
```

Inside example p1.setId() is possible . I understand that java is
 enabling the access of methods only inside another method. So its more
 secure. But I want to make clarification as why such restriction is
 there and what concept data abstraction or Encapsulation is shown with
 this restriction. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Is `Sample` supposed to be a class?

Comment: Can you please remove the empty lines and indent your code properly.

Comment: @Keppil - hope the edits are clear now

Comment: So is your question: "Why can't I call methods of instance variables in a `class` block?"...

Comment: yes exactly ...@veredesmarald

Comment: Well in that case, it's because you can't just have random statements in a `class` block.. The have to be inside a method body or a static block or an initializer... What would you expect such a statement to even do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that java is enabling the access of methods only inside another method. So its more secure

That's complete nonsense.

You're simply having problems with the syntax rules of the language, which say that inside a class body, [you can have only these four things:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6)

```
ClassMemberDeclaration
InstanceInitializer
StaticInitializer
ConstructorDeclaration
```

You can't put just any code inside a class, that's just not how classes are defined. You *can* use an instance initializer. This works:

```
public class Sample()
{
        Player p1 = new Player();
        Player p2 = new Player();
        Player p3 = new Player();
        Player p4 = new Player();

        {
            p1.setInt(2);
        }
}
```

But it's not usually done as constructors are more appropriate for instance initialization.

Comment: What are the empty brackets shortcut for?I never saw this before...

Comment: @PetrMensik those empty brackets works .. I have also heard it in this discussion for the first time

Comment: @Petr: as I wrote, that's an instance initializer, and a rarely used feature because constructors are more powerful.

Comment: fine, I googled it...what is the advantage over the constructor?is it good practise to use both of them?

Comment: @Petr: I can't think of any advantage except brevity. It's sometimes used for something called "double brace initialization" (more googling), but I consider that a horrible abuse and would be happy to see instance initializers removed from the language spec.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715485/what-is-the-difference-between-declaration-and-definition-in-java maybe this will help you understanding why you can´t use your method outside a method.

Answer (score 3):

**-** At class scope you **cannot** perform operation like that, at class scope

**-** Either it has to be `inside a method`, Or `inside a block` .

**Eg:**

```
public void go(){     // Inside a method

      p1.setIt(1);

   }
```

Eg:

```
{                    // Inside a block

      p1.setIt(1);

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you try to perform operation in class block, where methods and variables should be  defined.

If you really want to set this property use blocks.

```
public class Sample() {
    Player p1 = new Player();
    {
        p1.setId(1);
    }
}
```

I think better case to use some initialization method that will be called from constructor.

```
public class Sample() {
    Player p1 = new Player();
    public Sample() {
        init();
    }
    private init(){
        p1.setId(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that works .. But y is it restricted otherwise

Comment: I think it's OOP idea, you have class with state (variables) and behavior (methods) and there are nothing else suppose to be.

Answer (score -2):

and I think there might be another mistake in your code: why use parentheses after class name "Sample"?