# Java :Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token “)”, ; expected - Syntax error on token “(”, { expected

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am unable to find the mistake. Eclipse is giving me this error. Every `{` `}` is matching. Please help.

> Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token “)”, ; expected
>   - Syntax error on token “(”, { expected

My code is as follows :

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabInvocationException;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

class BackgroundImageJFrame1 extends JFrame {

public BackgroundImageJFrame1() {

    JButton b1;
    JLabel l1;
    final JFileChooser fc = null;
    final JTextField textField;
    final JButton jb1 = null;
    setTitle("Parallel Session");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("giphy.gif")));
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    l1 = new JLabel("Parallel Simulation Model");
    l1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    l1.setFont(new Font("Palatino Linotype", Font.BOLD, 20));
    l1.setToolTipText("Getting Started");
    l1.setBounds(86, 54, 219, 45);

    b1 = new JButton("\n\n LET'S GO!");
    b1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    b1.setFont(new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    b1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b1.setToolTipText("To begin click here!");
    b1.setBounds(120, 210, 272, 186);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setToolTipText("Progress");
    progressBar.setBounds(130, 207, 146, 14);

    getContentPane().add(l1);
    getContentPane().add(b1);
    getContentPane().add(progressBar);
    // Just for refresh :) Not optional!
    setSize(399, 399);
    setSize(400, 400);

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFrame Frame1 = new JFrame();
            final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

            JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Select your model");
            panel1.add(j1);
            JTextField jt1 = new JTextField();
            jt1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 20));
            panel1.add(jt1);
            new JButton("Browse");
            jb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
            panel1.add(jb1);

            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter the number instances");
            Frame1.setVisible(true);
            Frame1.setSize(300, 300);
            Frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            panel1.add(label1);
            Frame1.getContentPane().add(panel1);
            panel1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

            final JTextArea t1 = new JTextArea("Enter here");
            panel1.add(t1);

            JButton b11 = new JButton("SET");
            panel1.add(b11);

            jb1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    btnBrowseActionPerformed(null);
                }

            });
            private void btnBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                if (fc == null) {
                    fc = new JFileChooser(".");
                }

                // Show it.
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

                // Process the results.
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    textField.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                } else {
                    textField.setText("");
                }

                // Reset the file chooser for the next time it's shown.
                fc.setSelectedFile(null);

            }


             //done
                b11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    String a = t1.getText();
                    System.out.println(" " + a);
                    try {
                        int itr = Integer.parseInt(a);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= itr; i++) {
                            multi m = new multi();

                            JLabel l1 = new JLabel("MANUEVER DETAILS");
                            JTextArea p = new JTextArea(
                                    "Enter the manuever here");
                            panel1.add(l1);
                            panel1.add(p);
                        }
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException
                            | InterruptedException
                            | MatlabConnectionException
                            | MatlabInvocationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        ((Throwable) e).printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException,
        MatlabInvocationException, IOException {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("hey");

                new BackgroundImageJFrame1();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

}


}
```

Comment: You would be getting the line number that where you did the mistake

Comment: its shwing errror at the line  `private void btnBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {`

Comment: The actionperformed for b1 method has no closing bracket then the btnbrowseactioinperformed is declared. Thats the conflict.

Answer (score 4):

you have a method in a method, put btnBrowseActionPerformed method outside of BackgroundImageJFrame1

Answer (score 2):

You can not declare method inside method.

Take out `btnBrowseActionPerformed` method outside `BackgroundImageJFrame1()` constructor.

---

This code is written inside method.

```
jb1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
```

---

and this is a new method which should not be inside any method.

```
private void btnBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

---

**Note:** As mentioned by @Ranjeet, you need to [`declare`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715494/3898076) class level variables outside constructor, you can initialize inside constructor.

Comment: @NidhiVerma, Please have look at the `Note` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that was posted, the anonymous class definition ended after the actionPerformed() method using the symbols });

The btnBrowseActionPerformed() method is a private method of the same class and the class definition should include that method. Basically the }); that closes the anonymous class should be after the btnBrowseActionPerformed() definition.

```
jb1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    btnBrowseActionPerformed(null);
                }

            // do not close the anonymous inner class here
            //the below method belongs to the anonymous class.
            private void btnBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                if (fc == null) {
                    fc = new JFileChooser(".");
                }

                // Show it.
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

                // Process the results.
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    textField.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                } else {
                    textField.setText("");
                }

                // Reset the file chooser for the next time it's shown.
                fc.setSelectedFile(null);

            }
            });//close it here instead
```

Comment: This answer might or might not be correct, it is hard to tell what you are actually suggesting needs to be changed.

Comment: I have mentioned that in the comments. But yes I will make it clear. In the code that was posted, the anonymous class definition ended after the actionPerformed() method using the symbols    });The btnBrowseActionPerformed() method is a private method of the same class and the class definition should include that method. Basically the }); that closes the anonymous class should be after the btnBrowseActionPerformed() definition.

Comment: Please add this description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to write implementation of btnBrowseActionPerformed method outside constructor.
- Declare  final JFileChooser fc = null;  final JTextField textField;at class level not in constructor.
- It resolve your compilation error problem.