# Using a method without defining it?

Tags: java

I'm following a tutorial about Lambda, here I have this interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T> {
 public int compare(T t1, T t2); // What is this code???
 public default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<T> cmp) {
        return (p1, p2) -> compare(p1, p2) == 0 ? cmp.compare(p1, p2) : compare(p1, p2) ;
    }
public default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {

        return thenComparing(comparing(f)) ;
    }

    public static <U> Comparator<U> comparing(Function<U, Comparable> f) {

        return (p1, p2) ->  f.apply(p1).compareTo(f.apply(p2));
    }
}
```

The abstract method compare(t1, t2) is not defined anywhere; however, it is used in the thenComparing(comparator cmp) method. This thenComparing method then is used in the overloaded thenComparing() below. But if the compare() is not defined, what is the point of this line:

```
return (p1, p2) -> compare(p1, p2) == 0 ? cmp.compare(p1, p2) : compare(p1, p2) ;
```

Comment: Well `compare` will always be implemented by the time you actually call `thenComparing`, because it'll only be valid on a concrete instance of an implementing class...

Comment: `compare(t1 ,t2)` is not an abstract method, it is a method declaration in an interface. Small distinction really but the important part is the class that implements the interface cannot be constructed until all interface methods (in addition to all abstract methods) are provided a definition, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715485/what-is-the-difference-between-declaration-and-definition-in-java).

Comment: @KellyS.French - The JLS states that a non-default method in an interface is an abstract method.  See my answer.

Comment: @StephenC Cool! Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part of the interface that is relevant to your question:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T> {
     public int compare(T t1, T t2);

     public default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<T> cmp) {
         return (p1, p2) -> compare(p1, p2) == 0 ? 
             cmp.compare(p1, p2) : compare(p1, p2) ;
     }

     // rest deleted ...
}
```

First, the `public int compare(T t1, T t2);` statement is declaring an *abstract* method<sup>1</sup>.  Any concrete (i.e. non-abstract, instantiable) class must have an implementation for this method.  The Java compiler insists on this, and so does the JVM's classloader.

The method `thenComparing` is a default instance method.  This means that it will be called with a `this` that refers an instance of some class that implements `List`.  But, by the previous paragraph, this means that the `this` object *must* have an implementation for `this.compare(T, T)`.  That's the method that will be used in the `compare(p1, p2)` calls.

---

<sup>1 - The JLS states ([9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4)): *"An interface method lacking a default modifier or a static modifier is implicitly abstract, so its body is represented by a semicolon, not a block. It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the abstract modifier for such a method declaration."*</sup>