# passing value to member variable in java

Tags: java, class-members

Why can we do this:

```
class A{int a=5;}
```

but are not allowed to do this:

```
class A {
     int a;
     a=5;       
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between declaration and definition in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715485/what-is-the-difference-between-declaration-and-definition-in-java)

Comment: ok, but still it makes no sence that `a=5;` isn't allowed

Comment: Since they both would accomplish the same thing, why make the compiler and possibly the JVM more complicated than they have to be?  Why isn't `if (a < x <= 10) ...` allowed?

Answer (score 2):

just put it inside a block then.

```
class A {
     int a;
     {a=5;}       
}
```

An initialization block will run every time you make in instance of the class e.g.

```
new A();
```

this is of course between two other initializations related to creating a new instance.
first is the field's initializations like when you declare a field with a value.

```
int a = 25;
```

then the block initialization

```
{
  a = 5;
}
```

then the constructor:

```
A() {
    a = 6;
}
```

Comment: It's an initialization block.

Comment: I suggest you learn the basics in a book rather than stackoverflow