# How does declaration, definition and initialization work? I've stated how I understand it and would like to get corrected

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I've learned about declaration, definition and initialization. I seem to understand but still not so confident about it.

So I assume that declaration is putting (as well as declaring) a date type or a function (or something else perhaps I don't know) in the code and in most cases it's going to be a definition too. Basically everything that takes up memory could be considered both a declaration and a definition.

It could be a challenge making it intentionally of not being a definition. For example, we'd need to put `extern` specifier to a data type which'd drastically say: it. exists. don't. do. anything. And since functions don't take up memory, they in fact can be declared but not defined, such as `void function()`. When we open curly braces after the function, then it's officially considered a definition too.

Initialization is used to initialize the first value entered after the data type. So if the value is `int thing = 3`, the first value will be initialized as 3. But if we decide to reuse the `thing` variable while leaving the previous value behind and assign a value such as 4 (`int thing = 4`), then `thing` will be executed having value of 4.

Did I understand the concept right? It took me quite some time to read how others describe them as, so I'm wondering whether what I stated here is right or wrong.

Thanks for taking your time. I personally do not consider this as a duplicate as I'm reviewing my knowledge.

Comment: If you are looking for a standards version, `language-lawyer` tag will be useful.  Or do you just want a vernacular interpretation and/or confirmation that your understanding is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11715485/4117728

Comment: @Eljay I added the tag and yes, I'd like a confirmation that my understanding is correct.

Comment: Some good reading (if you haven't already read): [Definitions and ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) and [Function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)

Comment: Consider enhancing the question with code examples to help you nail down the sticking points. For example, I'm not entirely sure what you mean in the paragraph on initialization.

Comment: @user4581301 I fixed the paragraph of initialization, hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in simple terms you are correct. The [standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) devotes a page or so to declarations and definitions in par. 6.1. I liked how it described declarations (emphasis by me):

> A declaration (Clause 10) may **introduce one or more names** into a translation unit or redeclare names
> introduced by previous declarations.

The standard is vague about the nature of these names (in particular it doesn't mention "objects", "variables" or "types"!) because there is a great variety: Classes, functions, enum declarators, plain old variables, parameters, static class members etc.

The standard is also vague about the nature of this "introduction" because it varies as well. The common denominator is that a declaration gives the compiler enough information about the name to work with it it, although perhaps only in a restricted manner. For example, after the forward declaration of a class (`class MyClass;`) the compiler knows only that the name designates a type; but that's enough to define pointers to it (because all pointers to objects are created equal). It is not enough though to create an object of that type or call a method: The data and function members are, after all, unknown.

One can probably say that a *declaration* often specifies the outward properties — enough to use a name in some manner —, while a *definition* specifies the inner workings, i.e. what happens when it is being used.

For example, probably the most common "pure" declarations are function declarations, typically in headers. They inform the compiler how they can be called and which code must be produced to *call* them. A function *definition*, by contrast, specifies what happens when the function *is called*.

Similarly for a variable declaration vs. definition: *How can it be used vs. *what happens* when it is being used (which memory is manipulated).

The standard then goes on for half a page to list declarations which are not also definitions; about 10% of that are unknown terms for me (not sure whether that reflects badly on the standard or on me). With variables though, a declaration is, as you said, typically a definition unless it comes with the `extern` specifier and no initialization.