# difference between creating an object as a field or calling a constructor in Java

Tags: java, object

Noob alert. I have seen more of this questions but I'm not quite getting it.

Here is an object

```
Date date;
```

and another

```
Date date = new Date();
```

**What is the difference between the two ways and what are the downsides or upsides of using either of them?**

Comment: One creates an object. The other doesn't.

Comment: The first only creates a variable. The second creates both, a variable and an object/instance and then lets the variable refer to that. Just strictly differentiate variables from objects/instances in your head and your life will be simpler in Java.

Comment: Note that the `Date` class is legacy, you should not use it anymore. Instead, check out the classes available in the `java.time` package :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

- The first is a null reference variable.
- The second is a variable that holds a reference to a newly created object.

## Details

The first defines a variable to hold a reference to an object (instance) of the class `Date`. But there is no instance of `Date` yet. The variable holds no reference. We identify an empty reference as `null`. If you try calling a method via that null object reference, you’ll get a `NullPointerException`. No object means calling a method is senseless.

The second does the same, *plus*:

- Instantiates an object of the `Date` class.
- Assigns a reference to that new object to the variable.

---

By the way, both `Date` classes bundled with Java are terribly flawed in poor design. Never use them. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

- `java.util.Date` is replaced by `java.time.Instant`.
- `java.sql.Date` is replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date;
```

You don't create an object. You just declaration a new variable from Date type which is not assigned to an actual object, so it's null

```
Date date = new Date();
```

You declaration a new variable and assign it to an object

Comment: Actually/Technically the first one is *not* a definition but a declaration, the second one is declaration + definition :)
take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715485/what-is-the-difference-between-declaration-and-definition-in-java

Comment: I would not talk about Heap / Stack space here. First, you don't know if this is class member code, or class method code, or anything else. Second, you do not know how the JVM will handle that Date object, because modern JVMs are quite free to move the objects about as they please.